# Ore's "Graphs and Their Uses" Problem Set 1.5, Problem 2 ...

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Ore's classic book asks for a proof of the following. Is my proof correct?

> Show how each of four neighbors can connect his house with the other three houses by paths which do not cross (this is the part of Problem 1, which I have solved). A fifth person builds a house nearby; prove that he cannot connect his house with all the others by non-intersecting paths, but that he can connect it with three of the others.

Let’s say that the fifth person’s house is `e` and the (closed) curve `C` is formed by the four houses is `abcda`, where each of the four houses is connected to the other three. Let the curve `ac` lie inside `C` and curve `bd` lie outside `C` (both `ac` and `bd` can’t be simultaneously lying inside or outside `C` without intersections).

There are three possibilities to consider for the new house `e`:

1. `e` lies inside `C`.
2. `e` lies outside `C`.
3. `e` lies on `C`, between any two existing houses (say `a, b`).

In the first case, `e` could be trivially connected to `a, b`, and `c` or `a, d`, and `c` without intersections (depending upon whether `e` lies with respect to the closed curve `abca` or closed curve `acda`). If `e` lies inside curve `abca`, we can’t connect `e` (which lies inside `abca`) to `d` (which lies outside `abca`) without intersecting the curve `abca` (according to Jordan’s curve theorem). Similar reasoning applies if `e` lies inside the curve `acda` (in which case `b` lies outside `acda`). This proves that in this case, `e` can be connected to any three, but not all four houses without intersections.

In the second case, say that `e` lies outside the curve `C` such that we form a new curve `C`’ by connecting `ae, eb, bc, cd, da, ae`. We clearly keep the two existing curves `ac` (that lies inside `C` and also inside `C’`) and bd (that lies outside C and also outside C’). There are no intersections yet since we have two non-intersecting curves ab and ac inside curve `C’` and two non-intersecting curves `ed` and `bd` that are outside `C’`. But if we try to connect `e` to `c` so that `ec` lies inside `C`, it must intersect `ab` whereas it must intersect `bd` if we connect them so that `ec` is outside `C’`. Thus, `e` can be connected to `a, b, and d` without any intersections, but can not be connected to `c` without an intersection.

In the third case, consider that `e` lies on the curve `C` and we now have `C` formed by `ae, eb, bc, cd, da`. We retain `ab` (inside `C`), `ac` (inside `C`), and `bd` (outside `C`) without any intersections. We can also connect `ed` so that it lies outside, thus connecting `e` to `a, b` and `d` (three houses). But if we connect `e` to `c` such that `ec` is inside `C`, then it intersects `ab` which is also inside and if we connect `e` to `c` such that `ec` is outside `C`, it intersects `bd`. In either case, we have an intersection.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to verify your proof without any illustrations provided. As I understand it, though, your proof appears to be correct.

In fact this proof is a rather well-known one, and you've essentially proven that $K_5$, the complete graph on five vertices, is non-planar. Googling the phrase "*proof that K5 is nonplanar*" will return some non-trivial results, and you can compare your proof with others if you wish. It appears that most proofs of this make use of a corollary to Euler's formula:

> Given a planar graph with $e$ edges and $v$ vertices, we must have $e \leq 3v-6\;$.